# Why is F2 not creating a quad here, even though I have two adjacent open edges?

Tags: modeling, add-on, topology

I'm running 2.93 on Linux. Here's my situation (*see edit below for simpler case*):

[image]

I have the F2 Addon turned on, and I've verified that I don't have any doubled vertices or edges both by using the Mesh > Clean tools and by manually moving vertices around just to make sure.

When I press F, I would expect that a quad would be formed using the two adjacent open edges (From documentation: "An open edge is an edge which is only part of one face, or none at all.").

Instead, I get a triangle:

[image]

I know I'm missing something simple (probably in the topology) but my brain just isn't processing whatever the problem is and I'm going crazy. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I've broken down the mesh to the simplest case I can find that reproduces my issue, along with displaying the vert and edge counts to prove I don't have a degenerate topography.

I start with:
[image]

And after I press F I get:
[image]

Blender file can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vkseow5r3gQTJ8Trglo34bLbVu77MOUa/view?usp=sharing)

**EDIT 2**

I've made a video demonstrating me reproducing the problem, as other users have not been able to reproduce it with the posted blend file. I turned off all add-ons except for F2 before doing so.

Video can be found [here](https://imgur.com/a/43QI9UG)

**EDIT 3**

I've tracked the problem down to my configuration folder. If I go back to the default configuration the problem goes away. I'm going to go through my configuration and see if I can isolate what the problem is but at least I have a fix.

Comment: In your screenshot at the top I can't see two adjacent edges selected. Just a single vertex.

Comment: Should I be selecting the edges? From the F2 documentation: "When a single vertex is selected, a new quad is formed by creating a new vertex." (https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/mesh/f2.html)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about the "quad from vertex" method. It actually works when I try it myself, are you sure there is nothing wrong with the geometry? But I can't see a problem in the screenshot.

Comment: Yeah, I'll take another look and break down the mesh piece-by-piece.  Either I'll find something weird or I'll have a simple blend file to post.

Comment: I've added the simplest version of the problem I could construct and linked to a blender file. My suspicion is that there's some reason that those edges aren't considered open, even though they are only part of one face each.

Comment: I can't reproduce the behaviour, either ... is another add-on interfering? Try running F2 with no other add-ons enabled.

Comment: Your file is working correctly for me too... What vertex are you selecting?

Comment: I've added a link of video of me reproducing it without any add-ons except F2 for @RobinBetts

Comment: @Emir the one that has the 90 degree turn.  I've added video demonstrating it.

Comment: which release of blender?  I've just tried 2.93.0 on your blend file and the f key gives me the fill I would have expected; but with 2.83.9 I got the triangular face.  I think you've found a bug.

Comment: 2.93.0 -- I actually just added that info to the top of the question text along with my OS, but you can verify it on the bottom corner of my screen shots. @MartyFouts

Comment: What if you make a new plane, extrude an edge 90° Down and then try F2 with that plane? does it work?

Comment: @Emir I get the incorrect behavior when I do this. It looks like I get the wrong behavior on all cases where it's a vertex between two faces.

Comment: I've made progress tracking it down, and I think @MArtyFouts is right, I am seeing a bug from a previous version of the software.  The bug seems to be triggered by my configuration folder, because if I start with a fresh one the problem goes away.

Comment: I'm gonna see if I can track down what exactly is triggering it for the sake of completeness, but I found a solution at least.

Answer (score 1):

Restoring to the factory default configuration fixed the problem.

When I upgraded to 2.93 I attempted to keep my old configuration by manually copying over my configuration folder from the previous version.  You should not do this.

My userpref.blend from the previous version seems to have contained a bug that caused this to occur, and by copying over the file, I had imported the bug into the new version of Blender.